# Verification : Prove the Fubini-Tonelli theorem when $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is any measure space and $Y$ is a countable set with the counting measure.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

The Fubini-Tonelli theorem is valid when $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is an arbitrary measure space and $Y$ is a countable set $\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{P}(Y)$, and $\nu$ is counting measure on $Y$.

This is an exercise from Folland. I tried to prove this as in the proof of the original theorem, but as you can see below, the proof of the Tonelli theorem uses Theorem 2.36, which in turn requires the $\sigma-$finiteness of both measures. So how can I prove this? I would greatly appreciate any help.

**Edit**: I came up with a solution below but need it verified.

---

### My Attempt

For convenience, let $Y=\mathbb{N}$, and let $Y$ be the union of $Y_n=\{1,\dots, n\}$. Let $f\in L^{+}(X \times Y)$. Let $f_n=f\chi_{X\times Y_n}$. Then clearly $f_n$ is an increasing sequence converging to $f$, so we can use the Monotone Convergence Theorem later. Now we have:

$\int f_n d(\mu \times \nu)=\sum_{y=1}^n\int_{X\times y} f d(\mu \times \nu)=\sum_{y=1}^n\int_X f_n (x,y) d\mu(x)$.

$g_n(x)=\int f{_n}(x,y)d\nu(y)=\sum_{y=1}^n f_n(x,y)$.

$h_n(y)=\int f_n(x,y)d\mu(x)$.

$\int g_n(x) d\mu(x)=\int \sum_{y=1}^n f_n(x,y)d\mu=\sum_{y=1}^n \int_X f_n(x,y) d\mu(x)$.

$\int h_n(y) d\nu(y)=\sum_{y=1}^n \int_X f_n(x,y) d\mu(x)$.

Also, $\lim_n g_n(x)=\lim_n \sum_{y=1}^n f_n(x,y)=\lim_n \sum_{y=1}^n f(x,y)\cdot  \chi_{X\times Y_n}=\sum_{y=1}^\infty f(x,y)$.

and $\lim_n h_n(y)=\lim \int_X f_n(x,y) d\mu(x)=\int_X \lim f_n(x,y) d\mu(x)=\int_X f(x,y) d\mu(x)$ by the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

So the three integrals are equal, and now we can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem and the rest of the proof is identical to the one given below.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first equality is not so obvious for me: $\int f_n \mathrm{d}(\mu \times \nu ) = \int_{\mathbb{N}} \int_X f_n \mathrm{d}\mu \mathrm{d}\nu$

Answer (score 3):

There is only a need to prove the case where $f$ is a characteristic function. Following which, the rest of proof for theorem 2.37 applies.

To this end let $f=\chi_E$ where $E \subseteq X\times Y$. Writing $Y=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, we may write $E$ as a disjoint union of countably many rectangles $E=\coprod\limits_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^+} (E_n \times\{n\})$. Going back to the definition of $\mu \times\nu$ as an outer measure that extends the pre-measure on the algebra of "finite disjoint rectangles", we see that

$$(\mu\times\nu)(E)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)$$

That is,

$$\int \chi_E d(\mu\times\nu) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[\int \chi_{E_n} d\mu(x)\right] =\int \left[\int \chi_{E_n} d\mu(x)\right] d\nu(y)$$

We also know in general for $f_1,f_2,\dots\in L^{+}$ that $\int \sum f_n = \sum \int f_n$, so both of equations (2.38) are proven for $f$ being a characteristic function.

Comment: Why can we write the part of $E$ that's in $X$ as a countable union of $E_n$?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean preciselly by "the part of $E$ that is in $X$". All I am doing is defining $E_n := \{x\in X : (x,n) \in E\}$

Comment: Since ⊂×, =× for some ⊂, ⊂. You're effectively writing =∪. But okay I think I see: even though the union is countable, some of the $E_n$ may be uncountable.

Comment: I may recall wrongly as this is quite some time ago, but I don't think I assumed that $E$ is of the form $A\times B$. Each of the $E_n$ can be different as $n$ varies. On your question of countability, yes, the union is indexed over $n$ which runs over the positive integers.

Comment: I mistakenly assumed that any subset of $X \times Y$ must be of the form $A \times B$ for some $A \subset X, B \subset Y$. I understand now; thanks for the exchange.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!